# c# Deserializing json into object

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize this json using Newtonsoft but it returns nul on data. It works fine with code and message.

JSON:

```
{
  "Code": "0",
  "Message": "abc",
  "Data": [
      {
        "inventory_id": 7062,
        "text_fields": {
          "name": "name1"
        }
      },
      {
        "inventory_id": 7062,
        "text_fields": {
          "name": "name2"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Program.cs

```
async Task ProdAddWJson(string token)
{
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var baseLinkerClient = new BaseLinkerApiClient(httpClient, token)
    {
        ThrowExceptions = true
    };
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\\file.json"))
        {
           string json = r.ReadToEnd();
           Console.WriteLine(json);
            var inventory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJson>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(inventory);
            var products = inventory.products;
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(product);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (BaseLinkerException baseLinkerException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error! {baseLinkerException.ErrorCode} - {baseLinkerException.ErrorMessage}");
    }
}
```

Class

```
public class MyJson
{
    public string Code { set; get; }
    public string Message { set; get; }
    public List<AddInventoryProduct> products { get; set; }

}
public class AddInventoryProduct
{
    [JsonPropertyName("inventory_id")]
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("text_fields")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> TextFields { get; set; }

]
```

I'm expecting this code to create new instance of AddInventoryProduct which i can manipulate but data returns null.

Comment: in json its data in your object its products, try   public List<AddInvProduct> Data { get; set; }

Comment: The `Data` field doesn't match with the `products` in the JSON.

Comment: I tried and it still returns null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix your class attributes. And since you are using Newtonsoft.Json you have to use JsonProperty not JsonPropertyName

```
public class MyJson
{
    public string Code { set; get; }
    public string Message { set; get; }
    
    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public List<AddInventoryProduct> products { get; set; }

}
public class AddInventoryProduct
{
    [JsonProperty("inventory_id")]
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text_fields")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> TextFields { get; set; }
}
```